# I am calling the data from realtime firebase database but its not working

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am calling back the game_img_src and game_url and want all values to be callback automatically in my html page but unfortunately its not working , although its showing all game url in console.

here is my JS code for it

```
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

                                               
var reference = firebase.database().ref('Collected Data');
reference.on('value', function(snapshot)
{
snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot)
{
console.log(userSnapshot.val().game_url)
document.getElementsByClassName("/img_src").src = userSnapshot.val().game_img_src;
//document.getElementsById('gamename').innerHTML = userSnapshot.val().game_name;
document.getElementsByClassName("/game_url").href = userSnapshot.val().game_url;


});
});
```

Here is my html code where I want to display all games

```
    <div class="Added_games">
  <a id="game_url" class="/game_url"><img id="img_src" class="/img_src"></a>
  </div>
```